# Serve gzipped build in node.js

Tags: node.js, gzip

I'm trying to deploy my build with gzip (I'm using 'express-static-gzip'), but I still don't know how to do it correctly. This is what I've came up with so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const expressStaticGzip = require('express-static-gzip');

app.use(
    expressStaticGzip(__dirname),
);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'tvshows.tar.gz/.', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The gzipped file is in main directory of course.
It's this sendFile I have trouble with. How do I serve my index.html from gzip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/tkoenig89/express-static-gzip#usage), you should create a `index.html.gz` in the directory you want to express statically - in your case the directory is the application directory (`__dirname`).

So having the following folder structure

```
- app-dir
-- index.html.gz (each file has to be gzipped separately)
-- app.js
```

and

```
app.use("/", expressStaticGzip(__dirname)); // there's no need for adding a handler and manually using res.sendFile(..)
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: I did what you suggested - just renders a blank page... Oh, I forgot to mention it's a React build

Comment: eol answered correctly!

I'll just add that in case of my whole React build directory I had to gzip each file separately.